# How do I program a button to open react navigation drawer in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am a noob at React Native and I am confused on how to program a floating button to open the react-native navigation drawer.

As of right now I am calling the button in MapScreen.js. The button is called FloatingButton.js.

I have running into the error of "ReferenceError: Can't Find variable: navigation" when I press the button.

A bit of preface, I have been using burger menus on headers to open the drawer menu.

**App.js**

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
//import BottomTabNavigator from './navigation/BottomTabNavigator';
//import LinkingConfiguration from './navigation/LinkingConfiguration';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import MapScreen from './screens/MapScreen';
import LinksScreen from './screens/LinksScreen';
//import FloatingButton from './components/FloatingButton';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const LinksStack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const HomeStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#2a2a2a'
              },
            headerTintColor: '#fff'
          }}>
            <HomeStack.Screen name="Drive" component={HomeScreen} options={{
              headerLeft: () => (
                <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={25}
                backgroundColor = "#2a2a2a" onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()}></Icon.Button>
              )
            }} />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);

const LinkStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <LinksStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#2a2a2a'
      },
    headerTintColor: '#fff'
  }}>
    <LinksStack.Screen name="Links" component={LinksScreen} options={{
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={25}
        backgroundColor = "#2a2a2a" onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()}></Icon.Button>
      )
    }} />

  </LinksStack.Navigator>
);


export default function App(props) {

  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  
  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Drive" component={MapScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Links" component={LinkStackScreen} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#242C40',
  }
});
```

**MapScreen.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Maps from '../components/GoogleMaps';
import FloatingButton from '../components/FloatingButton';


export default class MapScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Maps
          style={ styles.map }
          />
        <FloatingButton style= {{bottom: 645, right: 380}} /> {/* broken button */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function DevelopmentModeNotice() {
  if (__DEV__) {
    const learnMoreButton = (
      <Text onPress={handleLearnMorePress} style={styles.helpLinkText}>
        Learn more
      </Text>
    );

    return (
      <Text style={styles.developmentModeText}>
        Development mode is enabled {learnMoreButton}
      </Text>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.developmentModeText}>
        You are not in development mode:
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#4B4B4B',
  },
  developmentModeText: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    color: '#BCBCBC',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 19,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  welcomeContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  welcomeImage: {
    width: 100,
    height: 80,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginTop: 3,
    marginLeft: -10,
  },
  getStartedContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 50,
  },
  homeScreenFilename: {
    marginVertical: 7,
  },
  codeHighlightText: {
    color: 'rgba(96,100,109, 0.8)',
  },
  codeHighlightContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    borderRadius: 3,
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
  },
  getStartedText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    color: '#E2E2E2',
    lineHeight: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  tabBarInfoContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: -3 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 3,
      },
      android: {
        elevation: 20,
      },
    }),
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#5F5F5F',
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
  tabBarInfoText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    color: '#E2E2E2',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  navigationFilename: {
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  helpContainer: {
    marginTop: 15,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  helpLink: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
  },
  helpLinkText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#2e78b7',
  },
  map: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
  }
});
```

**FloatingButton.js** I think this is where the problem lies, I think I am calling navigation wrong or
`onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()}` wrong.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Animated, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default class FloatingButton extends React.Component ({navigation}) { 

    render() {
        return (
      
            <View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.button, styles.menu]}>
                        <Icon name="ios-menu" size={25} color = "#fff" />
                    </Animated.View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View> 
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "absolute"
  },
  button: {
      position:"absolute",
      width: 45,
      height: 45,
      borderRadius: 60/2,
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      shadowRadius: 10,
      shadowColor: "#2a2a2a",
      shadowOpacity: 0.3,
      shadowOffset: {height: 10}
  },
  menu:{
      backgroundColor:"#2a2a2a",
  }
});
```

Here's what the MapScreen looks like
[image: MapScreen]

The error I get when I press the button
[image: Error]

Drawer menu
[image: Drawer Menu]

Home screen
[image: Home screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First option

In the map you can pass the navigation reference in a props like:

```
<FloatingButton
    style= {{bottom: 645, right: 380}}
    navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

then in your button component you can get the reference via the props and do:

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
```

## Second option

you can pass a callback to you component like:

```
<FloatingButton
    style= {{bottom: 645, right: 380}}
    isPressed={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
```

and call you callback like this in the button component

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> this.props.isPressed()}>
```

Answer (score 2):

if your button is not in navigation stack, so you have not navigation as props  then useNavigation is a good solution for you :

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

in your component:

```
  const navigation = useNavigation();
```

then :

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
    // your icon
  </TouchableOpacity>
```